# Нужно получить словарь методов из модуля math

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Мне нужно получить словарь методов из модуля `math`. Чтобы был вид словаря
`{'sin': sin, 'cos': cos ...}` но у меня получается совсем другое
`{'sin': "built-infunction sin"}` делаю я это с помощью `math.__dict__`
как мне привести словарь к нужному виду?

Comment: Приведите код своей попытки, чтобы пользователи могли лучше Вас понимать, более детально ответить на Ваш вопрос, указать Вам на Ваши ошибки и недоработки при их наличии, etc.

Comment: Нужно чтобы я мог воспользоваться этими функциями из словаря

Answer (score 3):

Пример:

```
In [52]: import math

In [53]: d = {'sin':math.sin, 'cos':math.cos}

In [54]: d['cos'](math.pi/2)
Out[54]: 6.123233995736766e-17

In [55]: d['sin'](math.pi/2)
Out[55]: 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

d = {value :value for value in dir(math)}

print(d)

выход :
{'__doc__': '__doc__', '__loader__': '__loader__', '__name__': '__name__', '__package__': '__package__', '__spec__': '__spec__', 'acos': 'acos', 'acosh': 'acosh', 'asin': 'asin', 'asinh': 'asinh', 'atan': 'atan', 'atan2': 'atan2', 'atanh': 'atanh', 'ceil': 'ceil', 'copysign': 'copysign', 'cos': 'cos', 'cosh': 'cosh', 'degrees': 'degrees', 'e': 'e', 'erf': 'erf', 'erfc': 'erfc', 'exp': 'exp', 'expm1': 'expm1', 'fabs': 'fabs', 'factorial': 'factorial', 'floor': 'floor', 'fmod': 'fmod', 'frexp': 'frexp', 'fsum': 'fsum', 'gamma': 'gamma', 'gcd': 'gcd', 'hypot': 'hypot', 'inf': 'inf', 'isclose': 'isclose', 'isfinite': 'isfinite', 'isinf': 'isinf', 'isnan': 'isnan', 'ldexp': 'ldexp', 'lgamma': 'lgamma', 'log': 'log', 'log10': 'log10', 'log1p': 'log1p', 'log2': 'log2', 'modf': 'modf', 'nan': 'nan', 'pi': 'pi', 'pow': 'pow', 'radians': 'radians', 'sin': 'sin', 'sinh': 'sinh', 'sqrt': 'sqrt', 'tan': 'tan', 'tanh': 'tanh', 'tau': 'tau', 'trunc': 'trunc'}
```

Comment: Я не смогу буду воспользоваться этими функциями

Answer (score 0):

Покажу пример работы с `dir` и `getattr`, для *получения словаря методов* из `math`:

```
import math

# Соберем словарь атрибутов модуля. Это переменные, классы, функции
name_by_attr = {name: getattr(math, name) for name in dir(math)}
print(name_by_attr)  # {'__doc__': 'This module is always available.  It provi...

# Отфильтруем атрибуты, оставив только функции и функторы (классы, которые ведут себя как функции)
name_by_func = {name: attr for name, attr in name_by_attr.items() if callable(attr)}
print(name_by_func)  # {'__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, 'acos': <built ...

# Еще фильтруем, оставив только те атрибуты, у которых в названии есть "cos" и "sin"
name_by_func2 = {name: attr for name, attr in name_by_attr.items() if 'cos' in name or 'sin' in name}
print(name_by_func2)  # {'acos': <built-in function acos>, 'acosh': <built-in function acosh>, ...
```

---

Можно и дальше итерировать фильтрацию, пока не получите нужный результат, но проще составить словарь, пример:

```
import math

name_by_func = {
    'cos': math.cos,
    'sin': math.sin,
    'tan': math.tan,
}

for name, func in name_by_func.items():
    print('{}: {}'.format(name, func(100)))
```

Консоль:

```
cos: 0.8623188722876839
sin: -0.5063656411097588
tan: -0.5872139151569291
```

Answer (score 0):

А в чём проблема-то? Из вашего словаря вполне нормально можно пользоваться функциями:

```
result = math.__dict__['sin'](1)
print(result)
```